# Как использовать внешнюю команду в Docker контейнере?

Tags: python, ubuntu, docker

**Система:**
Ubuntu 20.04

**Описание проблемы:** 
Нужно исполнить команду *latex* в Python-скрипте, который запускается в контейнере Docker'a. На машине установил texlive, команда *latex* работает и лежит в /usr/bin/. Однако при билде и ране скрипта в контейнере, функция `shutil.which("latex")` возвращает None, то есть исполняемый файл не найден

**Вопрос:** как получить доступ к команде *latex* из Python кода внутри Docker контейнера?

**Скрипт и Dockerfile**

```py
# script.py
import shutil
print(shutil.which("latex"))
```

```
# Dockerfile
FROM python:3.10

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/
WORKDIR /usr/src/

COPY . /usr/src/

CMD [ "python", "script.py" ]
```

Comment: Ты должен внутри докер-файла дописать комманду, которая ставит тех. То, что у тебя установлено в хосте - значения не имеет.